# Magento 2 - Override Configurable Product Attribute Label

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

In Magento 1.9 you used to be able to override the label for an attribute used in a configurable product (see below):

[image]

For example in the image above the default attribute label is Hanging Display Size, but when the 'use default' checkbox is unchecked, you can change it to e.g Width of Hanging Display.

In Magento 2.2 this option doesn't seem to exist. Am I missing it, or is it possible to restore this function?

Comment: After M1->M2 migration Magento (as of 2.4) uses the labels which are still stored in `catalog_product_super_attribute_label` although it does not provide an admin UI to edit them.

Comment: @MikhailChelevich can you confirm these labels are used in 2.4? I have tried this in my install, but it still seems to use the default attribute label, rather than the value in the catalog_product_super_attribute_label table.

Comment: the tables are used but M2 overwrites any custom labels on product save in the table. You need a customization for admin UI to show the text field and make the custom label saved to the table. After that the label is displayed everywhere

Answer (score 0):

There is no such options in M2 for specific product, you can with different store view.

You could change on fly (not a good practice) while displaying it in the front end, or create more specific attribute, on create a product attributes to use for it.